# Integrating PHP with Diffusion

Tags: php, push-diffusion, push-reappt

I can see from the docs how I can integrate a Java webserver, or an IIS but I can’t see how I can integrate our Apache servers using PHP with Diffusion or Reappt. I see there is a C client, but I don’t have remit to build a PHP wrapper for that. PHP is everywhere, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to integrate the server, but rather the client.

You could develop a JavaScript client (using the [JS API](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.6.7/js/index.html)) that is delivered by your HTTP server, and use it to connect to the Diffusion (or Reappt) server. The client will be able to access and subscribe to topics that are stored by the Diffusion server.

[image]

The scenario is:

1. Deliver HTML and JS to the browser
2. Use the Diffusion JS client inside the browser to connect to and subscribe to topics from the Diffusion server